# Is Spring Profile application context specific?

Tags: spring, profile, applicationcontext

I've created a web project with parent child application context configured. The root application context configured with infrastructure beans(`Datasource`, Transaction, ORM, Cache, security), and web application context configured with view resolvers, and all of this beans are group under relative profiles as follows:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>
            xml,
            cache,JDK,Ehcache,Redis,Memcache,xmemcached-Client,Composite,
            db,C3P0,
            orm,Hibernate,Hibernate4,
            transaction
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:servlet/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
            <param-value>xml,combined</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

when i try to lanch this project, i got this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheTestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.test.springbasic.service.impl.ContactService org.test.springbasic.controller.CacheTestController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.test.springbasic.service.impl.ContactService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I wanna know does spring profile application context specific (my controllers  under child context, and my services under root context and autowired to controllers), the `ContactService` is annotated with `@Profile({ "Hibernate" })`, why I can't get the bean, It is there, I've activated the "Hibernate" profile under `spring.profiles.default` context-param!

Answer (score 0):

Profiles can be activated in multiple ways. Let’s now see which one has priority over the other and what happens if you use more than one – from highest to lowest priority:

1. Context parameter in web.xml
2. WebApplicationInitializer
3. JVM System parameter
4. Environment variable

Based on the above information, the profiles set in `init-param` override the profiles set in `context-param`

Comment: Thanks, but when I add the "Hibernate" Profile to the <init-param>, It's worked, and due to your answer about the prority, I should not get the infrastructure beans, 'cause the profiles are ovrride by <init-param>

Comment: Thanks again. But this may not the right configuration.